# SpriteKit sound not playing

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sprite-kit

I'm trying to play a sound in my iOS SpriteKit application, like so:

```
var action = SKAction.PlaySoundFileNamed("filename.wav", false);
SKAction.RunAction(action, "action-name");
```

It's confirmed that the sound file does exist, because PlaySoundFileNamed would otherwise throw an exception.
I can also confirm that it is doing *something* as the application jitters slightly when the action is first executed (I know how to solve that, it's just to confirm it did something).

Things that I have tried:
- Set `waitForCompletion` on the `PlaySoundFileName` action to `true` instead of `false`.
- Invoke `AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true, out error)`
- Use a sound in *.wav* and *.m4a* format.
- Tested on both device and simulator.

But no sound is played...
Any ideas?

Comment: check that the sound file is mono, not stereo, and in a compatible format (ie uncompressed wav)

Comment: It was not uncompressed. Updated the to uncompressed wav, but still no sound.. It's a mono file.

Answer (score 2):

Still didn't get it to work with Sprite Kit, but I solved it by using the AVAudioPlayer.

```
public class SoundFile
{
    private AVAudioPlayer audioPlayer;

    public SoundFile(string fileName)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public bool PreLoaded { get; set; }

    public void PreLoad()
    {
        this.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(new NSUrl(this.FileName));
        this.audioPlayer.CurrentTime = 0;
        this.audioPlayer.NumberOfLoops = 0;
        this.audioPlayer.Volume = 1.0f;
        this.audioPlayer.PrepareToPlay();

        this.PreLoaded = true;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        if (!this.PreLoaded)
        {
            this.PreLoad();
        }

        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            this.audioPlayer.CurrentTime = 0;
            this.audioPlayer.Play();
        });
    }
}
```

then play it like this:

```
var sound = new SoundFile("my-filename.wav");
sound.Play();
```

(obviously pre-loading all the sounds first)